# AWS Cognito hosted UI signup: is it possible to drop username field?

Tags: amazon-cognito

Is it possible to elliminate `Username` field on sign-up screen?
[image: aws cognito hosted ui signup]

In the `Attributes` tab I have only one required field - `email`. And I do not know why but this menu is blocked - and I can not alter sign-in attributes from `Username` to `Email address or phone number`:
[image: aws Cognito attributes screen admin UI console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is select the 'Email address or phone number' option. These preferences can be modified only at the time of User Pool creation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is useful, but it may come in handy when you decide to automate the process with Terraform.

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "example_user_pool" {
  name = "example-user-pool"
  deletion_protection = "INACTIVE"
  mfa_configuration          = "OFF"

  username_attributes = ["email"]
  username_configuration {
    case_sensitive = true
  }
...
```

}

The key **username_attributes** essentially says "*Use the field(s) here instead of Username*". Currently Cognito allows you to use"*email*" and/or "*phone_number*" instead of "*username*".
With username_attributes set to ["email"], you will NOT see the "User name" field on Cognito's Hosted UI, which is what you want based on your post

Otherwise, Meghana Seetharam is correct. There are 3 checkboxes in the AWS Console when you first try to create the user pool. They control the behavior you are looking for.

Best of luck :)